# Parse XML files with null attributes in python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have many rows in the xml file and I'm trying to write a Python script that will go through those rows and update the null attributes to the AWS format. For instance, my tree looks like:

```
<TRANSFORMATION>
<ID_RSSD_PREDECESSOR>28</ID_RSSD_PREDECESSOR><ID_RSSD_SUCCESSOR>75026</ID_RSSD_SUCCESSOR>
<D_DT_TRANS/>
</TRANSFORMATION>
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-xml

How can I access the attributes with null values (`<D_DT_TRANS/>`) and update to :

`<D_DT_TRANS></D_DT_TRANS>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup for parsing/modifying XML documents. This example will fill all tags with zero content and insert empty string to them - effectively expanding `<tag/>` to `<tag></tag>`:

```
data = """<TRANSFORMATION>
<ID_RSSD_PREDECESSOR>28</ID_RSSD_PREDECESSOR><ID_RSSD_SUCCESSOR>75026</ID_RSSD_SUCCESSOR>
<D_DT_TRANS/>
</TRANSFORMATION>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_data = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')

for tag in xml_data.find_all(lambda t: len(t.contents) == 0):
    tag.string = ""

print(xml_data.prettify())
```

This will print:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TRANSFORMATION>
 <ID_RSSD_PREDECESSOR>
  28
 </ID_RSSD_PREDECESSOR>
 <ID_RSSD_SUCCESSOR>
  75026
 </ID_RSSD_SUCCESSOR>
 <D_DT_TRANS>
 </D_DT_TRANS>
</TRANSFORMATION>
```

Comment: This definitely works, but if the XML file is very large it will tak long hours to complete.